# How to define a meta tag for responsive layout?

Tags: html, css

Have I made a mistake when writing the code? And if not, is there another way to link CSS to HTML Page? I have tried a couple different ways of writing it but nothing seems to work.
Here's how I wrote it...

```
<head>
  <title>Quiz App</title>
  <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
```

I also tried...

```
<head>
  <title>Quiz App</title>
  <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link = rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `viewport` as `viewpoint` in your meta tag.

In your first snippet, change this:

```
<meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

To this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: @AndrewL64, try this, as this was very well documented, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62437585/13399106, and reopen this as it has been re-edited, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62458540/13399106